# Wifi modules with good linux drivers

Tags: 16.04, wireless, broadcom, hardware

I'm currently having HP 250 G4 and it has some broadcom wifi module, which has awful drivers for linux. I'm forced to sit very close to a router to have decent connection, and it still breaks sometimes. This is the case only for linux.

Could someone, please, list some wifi modules, which are known to be most reliable under linux and have reliable linux drivers, so I could buy one and replace my shitty one?

It would be super appreciated if you know, which ones are compatible with HP 250 G4, but still good if you don't.

I would appreciate both laptop wifi modules, so I could replace the broadcom one, and external, connectable via usb wifi receivers, but my primary interest is to find a good internal wifi module to replace my current one and have things working seamlessly.

UPD: results of running `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`, as requseted:

```
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:80c4]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
--
13:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Please edit the question to add results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`  The same module isn't responsible for bluetooth but there might be issues with bluetooth coexistence

Comment: @Jeremy31 done. Yep, it's another topic but I had problems with bluetooth coexistence

Comment: Is it really such a hard question, that no one has enough knowledge to answer?